# Using Django with OpenEdge Progress

Tags: python, django, pyodbc, openedge, progress-db

My colleague and I have been building custom reports for the last few months using Python, with the hopes of getting a Django application up and running into which we can put those reports. The database is Progress from OpenEdge, and we are allowed read-only access (proprietary software which we license).

Over the last 15 months, I've attempted different methods of getting Django connected to the database (pyodbc, pyodbcOpenEdge, etc.) and have been unable to get Django to successfully connect to the database. We can get SQL access via pyodbc - which we are using to run the Python scripts for reports, but can't get Django to work. I have been researching this issue for as long as we've been working on these reports.

Has anyone found a method to get Python 3.4, Django 1.8, and OpenEdge Progress 10.2B to talk to each other? Does anyone have any resources they can share with us?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/monasysinfo/pyodbcOpenEdge

Comment: I did; I forked it and tried to update it for Python 3.4, to no avail.

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying pyodbc? This support question says it could work: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000042052

Comment: What OS and driver are you using? Linux/FreeTDS? What is your `DATABASES` definition in your settings file? What Django python package are you using with `pyodbc`? I've got Python 3.4, Django 1.8 and SQL Server running with `django-pyodbc-azure`, as do many others.

Comment: YMMV, but my general experience has been that ODBC/JDBC connection to OE databases is always problematic, especially if other users are accessing the database natively and you are trying to write to it.  We're actually starting to use STOMP here to talk to OE to get around that.  (It sounds as if you have more immediate problems, but, just so you know.)

Comment: Andy - we've usually had little issues with ODBC access, but that STOMP is something I'll look into. 
Flipper - it's a Windows server.  Config looks like:

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
      'ENGINE' : 'OpenEdge.pyodbc',
   #  'DRIVER' : 'Progress OpenEdge 10.1B Driver',
   'DSN' : 'systemdsn',
   'NAME' : 'name',
   'DATABASE' : 'dbname',
      'SERVER' : '***.**.**.**',
   'PORT' : '#####',
      'UID' : '########',
      'PWD' : '########',
   'READONLY' : True }  
} 
It does not work with or without the driver statement. We're using pyodbc 3.0.10 and pyodbcOpenEdge 1.0.

Sorry, trying to figure out how to post here - please excuse the errors.

Comment: Have you had any luck during these years? Would be interested to learn if there is a workable solution to connect Django and OpenEdge DB.